# Why can't I double-click a button to create an event handler in Silverlight 2.0?

Tags: asp.net, wpf, winforms, silverlight

In WPF, ASP.NET, WinForms, I create a button, double-click on it and fill in the event handler.

In Silverlight (with Visual Web Developer 2008), I make a button, double-click it but nothing happens.

Is this not supported when writing Silverlight applications for some reason? Do we have to write these event handlers by hand?

Comment: What version of the silverlight tools are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 9.0.30729.146 of Silverlight Tools For Visual Studio SP1, why do you think this will someday be a feature? Since you can do it with WPF applications in XAML, it seems like the feature was just removed, perhaps to encourage Expression Blend use? Odd.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The silverlight designer is display only. If you want to move things on screen with your mouse or double click to add events, you need to use expression blend.

Answer (score 1):

This will be a feature in the next release of Silverlight along with many other developer tool improvements. You can create the event handler "semi-automatically" in the XAML-editor, though, using Intellisense.